# Использование таблиц в верстке устарело?

Tags: css3, html5

Использование таблиц в верстке устарело ?

Comment: Табличная вёрстка - да, таблицы - нет.

Comment: @L.F.C. https://learn.javascript.ru/traversing-dom#tasks инфа про таблицы актуальна ?

Comment: @L.F.C. я остановился на функциональном стиле https://learn.javascript.ru/  можно 2 главу изучать ?

Comment: Вы не можете знать наверняка в какой ситуации потребуется таблица, так что учить надо.

Comment: а 3 комментар ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не то, чтобы устарело, но использование таблиц порождает минимум две проблемы:

1. Смешивание содержимого и оформления. На мелких страницах некритично, но легко перешагнуть черту, после которой разметка превратится в большую и неразборчивую мешанину, в которую очень тяжело вносить изменения.
2. Жёстко зашитое взаимоположение частей страницы. Проще единожды подправить CSS-свойство, чем перевёрстывать всю таблицу.

Также, возможно, табличная вёрстка сбивает с толку поисковые системы.

Comment: 3. Про адаптацию под мобильные устройства можно забыть (или как минимум делать через костыли).